# Register Dataset to Azure ML using Axure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-machine-learning-service, mlops

```
datastore = Datastore.register_azure_blob_container(
            workspace=workspace,
            datastore_name=datastore_name,
            account_name=datastore_account_name, # Storage account name
            container_name=datastore_container_name, # Name of Azure blob container
            account_key=datastore_account_key) # Storage account key

dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path = [(datastore, 'udata.csv')])

registered_dataset_name = 'udata set'
registered_dataset_description = 'sample dataset'

dataset.register(workspace=workspace,name=registered_dataset_name,description=registered_dataset_description)
```

I'm trying to run a python script from azure devops pipeline which will register the data from azure storage to Azure datastore and create dataset. The python script works fine. The registration of Datastore and dataset happens correctly.

But I'm getting an error in Devops pipeline

> ERROR: UserErrorException:
> Message: Failed to load dataset definition with azureml-dataprep==4.12.4. Please install the latest version with "pip install -U azureml-dataprep".

Comment: Are you using a MS-hosted agent or a self-hosted agent? Did the pipeline run successfully? You can try to run the same python scripts on your local machine and check whether you can see the same error message or not. According the message, it seems that you need to install the latest azureml-dataprep, you can add a command line task before your python scripts and run `pip install -U azureml-dataprep`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a MS-hosted agent. Datastore and Data asset creation is successful in Azure ml and experiment in jobs shows completed. Devops pipeline fails 
ERROR: UserErrorException:
 Message: Failed to load dataset definition with azureml-dataprep==4.12.4. Please install the latest version with "pip install -U azureml-dataprep".
 InnerException None
 ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Failed to load dataset definition with azureml-dataprep==4.12.4. Please install the latest version with \"pip install -U azureml-dataprep\"."
    }
}

Comment: I have added a script before running the python code, it still fails
script: |
    pip install -U azureml-dataprep
  displayName: 'Update azureml-dataprep'

Comment: You can run the same python scripts on your local machine and check whether you can see the same error message or not. If you don't see the same error, set up a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install) on your local machine and run the same pipeline on it. If you see the same error locally, the issue seems to be not related to the pipeline.